# Putting form validation on html controls in razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, validation

I have been facing an issue of putting form validation on html controls any one guide me how to resolve this issue?

**My HTML Field In something.cshtml**

```
<input type="text" id="AccidentDate" name="AccidentDate" />
@Html.ValidationMessage("AccidentDate")
```

**Controller code:**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public ActionResult Index(Models.c objC)
 {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(objC.AccidentDate))
     {
         ModelState.AddModelError("AccidentDate", "*");
     }

     return View(objClaimant);
  }
```

Please note validationMessage does raise error in the form of * in-front of that input field but my requirement is to highlight that input field as red.

**MOST IMPORTANT I KNOW IF I USE:**
`@Html.TextBox("AccidentDate", Model.AccidentDate);` it works perfectly but using this is not my requirement.

finally, i am looking to make html input field red through any other way, if validation message is raised.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you'd need to recreate all the unobtrusive validation attributes on the input. Put in @Html.TextBox("AccidentDate", Model.AccidentDate);, view source, cut and paste?

Comment: Also the attributes will depend on the validation attributes you've put on your model, so what do you want to validate??

Comment: Also I'm presuming you want to use the unobtrusive validation engine??

Comment: i just need to highlight that textbox in case of input field is empty validation message is raised so is there any tweak to put css of error if validation message is raised?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so rather than just commenting I figured I'd try and help. So I'm presuming you want to use the [unobtrusive validation engine](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

So if you do

```
@Html.TextBox("AccidentDate", Model.AccidentDate);
```

and view source you'll see something like:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The AccidentDate field is required." 
   id="AccidentDate" name="AccidentDate" type="text" value="">
```

So the important thing to notice are the `data-val` attributes. These basically tell the unobtrusive engine, *"this field needs to be validated and this is how and what to display if it fails"*

So to do this without `@Html.TextBox` **which does all this for you**, you'll need to create these attributes yourself in your HTML.

**Quick an dirty solution**, put your `@HTML.TextBox` in, run your code cut&paste the HTML. May not be what you want?

**Edit**
you want the required validation, so the above `data-val="true" data-val-required="The AccidentDate field is required."` attributes are what you need, obviously substituting your own error message

so:

```
<input type="text" id="AccidentDate" name="AccidentDate" 
   data-val="true" data-val-required="The AccidentDate field is required." />
@Html.ValidationMessage("AccidentDate")
```

**Css Class**

The Css class should be being applied. The relevant piece of code is:

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element
        var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
            replace = $.parseJSON(container.attr("data-valmsg-replace")) !== false;

        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
        error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);

        if (replace) {
            container.empty();
            error.removeClass("input-validation-error").appendTo(container);
        }
        else {
            error.hide();
        }
    }
```

inside the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. confirm your referencing this js file and see if the above code is hit?

Comment: I have put these two attributes inside input field but it does not heightlight the input field: reason is it still dont has any effect on it, but validation message is raised as previous. further looking at detail i got to know it is not putting "field-validation-error" css on that field in case of error, that is the reason.

Comment: That's odd, the code to do this should all be included in the unobtrusive.js script

Comment: Are you adding your form using `@using(Html.BeginForm())`??

Comment: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> included as well as beginform

Comment: Must be something in that onError method, you'll have to debug it though as I'm out of ideas.

Comment: thanks for your idea, let me investigate and post my answer here if i found something useful.